# unordered_map with class object as value

Tags: c++, unordered-map

When I attempt to compile this code

```
class t
{
public:
  int v;
  // t() = default;
  t(int i) : v{i} {}
};

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
  unordered_map<int, t> test;

  test.emplace(1, 4);
  std::cout << test[1].v << std::endl;
}
```

I get the error

```
                    ^
test.cpp:39:20: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unordered_map<int, t, std::__1::hash<int>, std::__1::equal_to<int>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, t> > >::operator[]' requested here
  std::cout << test[1].v << std::endl;
                   ^
test.cpp:30:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'i', but no arguments were provided
  t(int i) : v{i} {}
  ^
test.cpp:25:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class t
      ^
test.cpp:25:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
```

When I uncomment the `t() = default` line, the code compiles and the output is `4` as expected. The value for the key `1` was already constructed with `test.emplace(1, 4);`. So when I do `test[1]`, shouldn't this be returning a reference to an instantiated `t` object? Why is it trying to default construct the object?

Comment: Short answer: Subscripting won't work on an `unordered_map` if the value type does not support default construction.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm I see. i had thought this only applied if there an object for the key wasn't already created.

Comment: No, but `test.at(1).v` would work.